# ASP NET MVC 5 SeletList DropDownList

Tags: asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu, selectlist

I have some problems with SelectList and DropDownList.
Ich have the two Models (TimeRecord has a navigation-property to Project):

```
public class Project
{
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string ProjectName { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class TimeRecord
{
    public int TimeRecordId { get; set; }
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public Project TmRecProject { get; set; }
}
```

In my Controller in the Create-action method the SelectList is pass by ViewBag to the View (till now all is correct working)

```
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.ProjectId = new SelectList(db.Projects, "ProjectId", "ProjectName");
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(TimeRecord timeRecord)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.TimeRecords.Add(timeRecord);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(timeRecord);
    }
```

Here is the View:

```
@model SelectListDropDownTest.Models.TimeRecord

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>TimeRecord</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TmRecProject.ProjectId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("ProjectId", null, new { @class = "form-control" } )
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

In the Create-View I can select a Project from the DropDownList. My Problem is when I pass the Model "TimeRecord" back to the Controller the Project "TmRecProject" is always null.

What is the best way to solve this Problem?

Comment: You need the `ProjectId` (not `TmRecProject`) to be bound which is what your code is doing (although badly) - its the value of `ProjectId` which will be updated when you save the data. Your implementation means that you will not get client side validation and the name of the `SelectList` needs to be different from the property your binding to so that in the view its `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ProjectId, (SelectList)ViewBag.ProjectList, new { @class = "form-control" })` In any case, your editing data so always use a view model

Answer (score 0):

First of all I am not able to understand how are you able to select value from dropdown list as you have not bind your 'ViewBag.ProjectId' with your drop down list.
Change in your view and your code will start working !!!!

**Change:**

Bind the drop down list with the model in View.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.TmRecProject.ProjectId, ViewBag.ProjectId as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Others are as it is and you will get data on your post method.

Comment: No it doesn't work...the result is the same like in my example

Comment: Thats better, but problem now I got the ProjectId but the ProjectName is null (in TmRecProject). and my ModelState.IsValid returns a false. But you gave teh right tip to solve the problem...

Comment: You will get the 'ProjectName' null as you need only the 'Value' property back to your post method.